# Not able to validate against imported XSD

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xml-namespaces, xsd-validation

I am trying to validate my XML against an XSD which is imported in another XSD.

Please have a look at the following code:

**xml1.xml:**

```
<e1 xmlns="n1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="n2 main.xsd">
</e1>
```

**xsd1.xsd:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="n1"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xsd:element name="e1"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

**main.xsd:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="n2"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xsd:import namespace = "n1" schemaLocation = "xsd1.xsd"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

Validating xml1.xml (in netbeans with xml tools or in java) simply  throws:

> ```
> cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'e1'. [3]
> ```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model of `xsi:schemaLocation` requires adjustment.  It is ***not an include statement*** that automatically brings XSDs into scope; it is a ***hint*** that says for a given namespace where validation might be able to find an appropriate XSD.

When you declare, `xsi:schemaLocation="n2 main.xsd"`, you're hinting to look in main.xsd for the `n2` namespace, but you've said nothing about the `n1` namespace actually associated with your root element.  Validation encounters the root element in the `n1` namespace, consults your hints, finds nothing, and let's you know:

> ```
> cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'e1'. [3]
> ```

as it should.   Your path forward is clear:  **Add a hint for the `n1` namespace of your root element:**

```
    xsi:schemaLocation="n2 main.xsd n1 xsd1.xsd"
```

and your XML document will validate successfully.

Comment: Thank you! BTW I expected that because I imported the xsd1 schema into the main schema it is enough to refer only to the main as it contains the imported namespace. I starting to realize that it doesn't work this way but i need to bind the imported namespace to a prefix and use it in the main schema. Besides i am sure your answer was good, thanks again!